# Having a jsTree with checkboxes, how can i disable all checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have a jsTree, built dynamically, that allows the user to select whatever nodes he chooses.

Now i'm trying to make this tree readonly so that other users can see the information without altering it.

All examples i find are about disabling a specific node...

My question is: Is there a way to define all the checkboxes on the tree to readonly?

Code being used:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(
    function() {
        jQuery("#divTree").jstree(
            {
                "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "checkbox", "sort", "ui", "real_checkboxes"],
                json_data: { data: data }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: When you say read only, do you mean disable all the UI options (rename, move, add, delete etc)?

Comment: My tree doesn't allow all those actions. After rendered it's only a simple tree with checkboxes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem Solved. Here is the solution for anyone that needs it.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(
    function() {
        jQuery("#divTree")
        <% if(isReadOnly) { %>
        .bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) 
             {
            jQuery('.jstree a').click(function() {return false;});
        })
        <% } %>
       .jstree(
                {
                    "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "checkbox", "sort", "ui", "real_checkboxes"],
                    json_data: { data: data }
                }
            );
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thank You. I was looking for a solution for this for a while now, and your solution is simple and elegant!

Comment: One catch is that with that approach, when a node expands / collapses, the checkboxes become enabled. To address that, I added another event listener for 'after_open.jstree' even to do the same.

Comment: If tree is has complicated structure, that works only on top level nodes. So, you should use event "ready.jstree" instead of "loaded.jstree".

Comment: Not true, tree has 3 levels and this solution works on all levels

Answer (score 0):

You can define this in your default `type`, or define your own `type` for specific nodes then bind them to it:

```
jQuery("#divTree").jstree({
    "types": {
        "default": {
            "check_node": false,
            "uncheck_node": false
        }
    },    
    "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "checkbox", "sort", "ui", "real_checkboxes"],
    "json_data": { data: data }
});
```

If I were you, I'd just wrap that `types` declaration inside a server side `if` statement to determine whether you want this tree to be read only or not.

**Docs:** http://www.jstree.com/documentation/types

Comment: I've tried your solution but the tree is still editable... +1

Comment: Do you have other types of nodes?

Comment: Doesn't work and there seems to be no reason for it to work since none of the code in the checkbox plugin checks if it is allowed to be checked.