# How to disable the entire jstree in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I tried disabling entire list of checkboxes in jstree using disable attribute in jquery `$(divid).attr("disabled",true)` but it didn't work. Is there any way to disable jstree?

Comment: Please check this link .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491989/having-a-jstree-with-checkboxes-how-can-i-disable-all-checkboxes